# Does the Rite of Fleshmoulding allow you to exceed the normal limit on Fear?

Tags: black-crusade

I was flipping through the Tome of Excess yesterday and I noticed that the Rite of Fleshmoulding can grant Fear (X) to a victim. 
Now, the rite of flesh moulding states that for every success after the first you can raise a Trait(X) stat by one to a maximum of six. However, the Fear trait caps out at Fear(4) in the core book.

By RAW, could the Rite of Fleshmoulding grant Fear(6) if enough successes was rolled, and would a Fear rating above 4 do anything except waste points?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**No it does not**

The fear trait cannot exceed a max of 4. This is a simple case of specific rule beats general rule.

The general rule here is that each success raises a Trait(X) by one to a maximum of six.
The specific rule is The maximum rating of fear is 4.

So when using the Rite of Fleshmoulding you can use extra successes to raise the Fear Trait to a max of Fear(4) and any excess successes are wasted. Just like with other traits if you would get past the Rites maximum of 6